# How can I do to update a row like a pro?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8

```
    package gestionoutilbricolage;
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel; 
    import javax.swing.JTable;

    public class FenetreListeOutil extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String outil;
    Statement stmta;    
    Statement stmt;
    Statement stmtListeOutil;
    Connexion maconnexion = new Connexion();

    public FenetreListeOutil() {

            initComponents();

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

            model.addColumn("NOM DE L' OUTIL"); 
            model.addColumn("FABRICANT");
            model.addColumn("ANNEE DE FABRICATION");
            model.addColumn("PRIX");

            String  requeteListeOutil = "select *from outil"; 
            try{
            stmtListeOutil=maconnexion.ObtenirConnexion().createStatement();
            ResultSet resultat = stmtListeOutil.executeQuery(requeteListeOutil);
            while(resultat.next()){
            model.addRow (new Object[] {resultat.getString("nom_outil"),resultat.getString("fabricant_outil"),resultat.getString("annee_fabrication"),resultat.getString("prix_outil")});
            }
            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
            }
            TableOutil.setModel(model);
            }
            private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            String sql = "DELETE  FROM `outil` WHERE nom_outil='outil B'";
            try{
            stmt=maconnexion.ObtenirConnexion().createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            }    
            catch(SQLException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
            }    
            }  
            private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            int ligneSelectionne = JTable.getSelectedRow(); 
            String outil = JTable.getValueAt(ligneSelectionne, 0);  
            stmt=maconnexion.ObtenirConnexion().createStatement();
           String wql = "UPDATE outil SET nom_outil=outil A"; 
           stmt.setString(1, outil); 
           stmt.executeUpdate(wql);
           }                     
           public static void main(String args[]) {

            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FenetreListeOutil.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FenetreListeOutil.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FenetreListeOutil.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FenetreListeOutil.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            new FenetreListeOutil().setVisible(true);
            }
            });
            }
            // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
            private javax.swing.JTable TableOutil;
            private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
            private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
            private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
            private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
```

I would want to know if there is another way without being obliged every time to go into my rêquête to change parameter.
How make the professionals in computing in their application where we select any line of the table with the mouse then we press on the button to update and that update right now.

My update code has errors. The errors are:

```
setString cannot be find symbol,
Non static method getselectedrow() can not be referenced from a static context,
Non static method getvalue() can not be referenced from a static context.
```

My new code after tips:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
// TODO add your handling code here:
  int ligneSelectionne = TableOutil.getSelectedRow(); 
String outil = TableOutil.getValueAt(ligneSelectionne, 0); 
  PreparedStatement stmt = null;
String wql = "update outil Set nom_outil = ? where nom_outil = ?";
try {
    maconnexion.setAutoCommit(false);
    stmt = maconnexion.prepareStatement(wql);
    stmt.setString(1, "outil A");
    stmt.setString(2, "outil avant");
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    maconnexion.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
      JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
        if (maconnexion != null) {
            try {
                System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                maconnexion.rollback();
            } catch(SQLException excep) {
                JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }

    maconnexion.setAutoCommit(true);
    }


}
```

setAutoCommit, commit, JDBCTutorialUtilities, rollback are cannot find symbol.

I have difficult to apply your answer because I am novice in sql and java so I use this video to make my application https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FS7DiKROaCg

Comment: Please translate your variable and class names to English in your example and please indent your code properly. As it is right now, it is very hard to read (especially for a person who does not speak french).

Comment: 1) One question each time per post; 2) Search previous answers before posting questions (static vs non static have LOTS of answered question, symbol not found also appear often). 3) State your question clearly (it is not clear if you are asking to improve an already working code, which issues you have, etc). 4) Indent properly your code. 5) Names of variables in english may help getting more atention, but **are not required**

Comment: @Dargondraikk do you need to translate the name of variables to know what the cause of `cannot find symbol` or `Non static method cannot be referenced from static context` is?

Comment: I  search an anwser before and my update code doesn't work.

Comment: Go to the search box and type "non-static method cannot be referenced java", for example

Comment: Why do people still code in another language than English? :s

Comment: Because I don t speak english

Comment: I search box and type and I don't find a answer to my problem. can I have a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. "TableOutil" should be "tableOutil". Notice how the variable is highlighted differently in your posted code. That is because upper case characters are used for "class names".

```
int ligneSelectionne = JTable.getSelectedRow(); 
String outil = JTable.getValueAt(ligneSelectionne, 0);
```

You are referencing the "JTable" class. You want to reference the instance of the class you created:

```
int ligneSelectionne = tableOutil.getSelectedRow(); 
String outil = tableOutil.getValueAt(ligneSelectionne, 0);
```

Comment: int ligneSelectionne = TableOutil.getSelectedRow();   it's ok now thanks.

Comment: String outil = TableOutil.getValueAt(ligneSelectionne, 0);  is not ok ,  Netbeans tell me incompatible types required: java.lang.string.  Found: java.lang.Object

Comment: @jeffrey245, 1) Your variable name is still incorrect!!! Follow Java standards and listen to the suggestions you have been given!!!. 2). Then invoke the `toString()` method on the value returned by the get getValueAt(...) method.